# Excel Day shift and night shift schedule

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, time, formula

Lets say I have two shifts at work.

- Day shift is from 7:00 to 17:30
- Night shift is from 18:00 to 4:30

Based on this numbers I want excel to return if its "Night Shift" or "Day Shift"

This is what i have so far with the IF statement

```
=IF(Q2>=7,"DAY SHIFT",IF(Q2<=17.3,"DAY SHIFT",IF(Q2>=18,"NIGHT SHIFT",IF(Q2<4.3,"NIGHT SHIFT"))))
```

But im not getting the results I want. Any ideas to correct the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is what you are looking for, assuming that cell `Q2` is a Date/Time value.

```
=IF(AND(MOD(Q2,1)>=(7/24),MOD(Q2,1)<=(17.5/24)),"Day Shift",IF(OR(MOD(Q2,1)<(4.5/24),MOD(Q2,1)>=(18/24)),"Night Shift",""))
```

The `MOD(Q2,1)` extracts the time portion of a date/time cell. These values are stored as decimal numbers, where 4:30 AM would be represented by `4.5/24 = 0.1875` (note that 30 minutes is half an hour, hence 4:30 AM is represented by 4.5/24 instead of 4.3/24, which would be 4:18 AM).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

`=IF(AND(Q2>=7,Q2<=17.5),"DAY SHIFT", "NIGHT SHIFT")`

But if you want to specify the "Night Shift", this would be better:

```
=IF(AND(Q2>=7,Q2<=17.5),"DAY SHIFT", IF(OR(Q2>= 18, Q2<4.5), "NIGHT SHIFT",""))
```

Comment: This doesn't work, for reasons I describe in my post.

Comment: It does work, it simply depends on how Q2 is formatted (could be a manual input). He didn't specify the format, so neither did I. In hindsight, I should have asked for more detail. However, you answer is more thorough and detailed, so I gave you a +1.

Comment: Thank you. The issue was in the times, however. 17.3 = 17:18. I updated the post to reflect this and returned the favor. This is a valid solution for numeric entries in Q2.

Answer (score 0):

A little shorter:

```
=IF(OR(Q2<4.5/24,Q2>=3/4),"Night",IF(AND(Q2>=7/24,Q2<=17.5/24),"Day","?"))&" Shift"
```