# Day shift and night shift in Excel

Tags: excel, function

My company has 2 shifts, day and night. day shift starts from 06:00am to 18:00pm and night shift starts from 18:00pm to 06:00am. I have a column in excel which has time. But how can I categorize the shifts based on the information given and time in Excel?

```
=IF(OR(G2>=TEXT(TIME(18,0,0),"AM/PM"), G2<TEXT(TIME(6,0,0),"AM/PM")), "Day", "Night")
```

Comment: Hi welcome to Stackoverflow. You have to indicate the data type of your time column (it is really a time or a text showing time). Also, you cannot use `TEXT` function to do comparison because operators can only accuratelty compare time in numeric form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel Day shift and night shift schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50951531/excel-day-shift-and-night-shift-schedule)